# Navbar switch between pages Bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Keep hitting a big issue on an altered website template using bootstrap 3.1.1. Need the Navbar to link both to parts of the page that's open, and to other parts on different pages of the site. Navbar as is switches to the parts of the same page just fine, but won't switch to the parts of the other pages.  I cannot work out why, everything seems to be correct?

I confuse easily, alas

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Description</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="index.html#x">Home</a></li>
        <li><span>/</span></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#a">Description a</a></li>
        <li><span>/</span></li>
        <li><a href="index.html#b">Description b</a></li>
        <li><span>/</span></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html#s">Description c</a></li>
        <li><span>/</span></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html#r">Description d</a></li>
        <li><span>/</span></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you linking correctly to the ID's on the other pages? - You may need to show more of your code.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I definitely have- if I right click and open the link in a separate window, it goes right to the correct spot on the correct page. Just won't fire when clicked.
What else would you need to see? Can post with pleasure, but not sure what else is needed.